# Find the largest number in a pool of integers

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have been working on this code for quite a while now and frankly, I have no more ideas on how to solve this. I have sought different threads on how to do this, unfortunately, still have no answers.

To start off, I have this pool of data that is a string but needs to be considered as a list. For example:

```
# empDataLT
200401003,Luisa,Jurney,Accounting,800,21,4/8/2002,;
200208006,Clorinda,Heimann,Accounting,1050,15,5/21/1994,;
200307014,Dick,Wenzinger,Admin,565,15,10/13/1973,;
200901005,Ahmed,Angalich,Purchasing,750,20,2/10/1973,;
200704013,Iluminada,Ohms,Marketing,750,16,7/13/1972,;
201701018,Joanna,Leinenbach,Finance,1050,15,11/6/1980,;
201003007,Caprice,Suell,Admin,750,18,6/28/1992

a = empRecords.strip().split(";")
```

This pool is in the format: Employee Number, First name, Last Name, Department, Rate per day, No. of Days Worked, Birthdate

What I have been trying to do is to compute the employees' rate per day multiplied to the number of days worked, then find which of them is the highest earning employee. I have the following code which works decent, but of course it lacks the latter result needed (aka, the highest earning).

```
import empDataLT as x 

def earn():
    empEarn = list() # convert module to a list
    for er in x.a:
        empErn = er.strip().split(",")
        empEarn.append(empErn)
    b = sorted(empEarn, key=lambda x: x[4])
    for e in b:
        ern = (int(e[4]) * int(e[5])) 
        print(ern)
```

This will result to something like this:

```
20800
14400
21600
24000
12800
24000
```

Which is great because I have the result (yay). However, I am unable to look for the highest earning as I usually get error when I try `max()` since it's an integer. I tried converting it to a `str` then use `max()` and it will just give me the highest number per integer.

I'm not really sure what to do anymore.

Comment: `max()` works great with integers.  What's your real problem?

Comment: When I use `max()` in here, I get an error of `TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this :

```
empRecords = '''200401003,Luisa,Jurney,Accounting,800,21,4/8/2002,;
200208006,Clorinda,Heimann,Accounting,1050,15,5/21/1994,;
200307014,Dick,Wenzinger,Admin,565,15,10/13/1973,;
200901005,Ahmed,Angalich,Purchasing,750,20,2/10/1973,;
200704013,Iluminada,Ohms,Marketing,750,16,7/13/1972,;
201701018,Joanna,Leinenbach,Finance,1050,15,11/6/1980,;
201003007,Caprice,Suell,Admin,750,18,6/28/1992'''

a = empRecords.strip().split(";")
earn = []
for i in a:
    t = i.split(',')
    cur = int(t[4])*int(t[5])
    earn.append(cur)
    print(cur)
print("Maximum Earning :",max(earn))
```

Comment: Oh, this works really well. Do you mind explaining the logic of that?

Comment: It's just appending the values `cur` to a list `earn` and then using `max` on the list. In your original example, you're trying to get the `max` of a single integer as opposed to something iterable (such as a list). This is clean code. I'm not sure which is more efficient--appending to a list and doing max once, or doing max over each iteration but not having to append the values (see: Putnam's answer). Either way should work.

Answer (score 0):

You can use max, you just need to keep the previous largest-found:

```py
highestEarning = 0
for e in b:
    highestEarning = max((int(e[4]) * int(e[5])),highestEarning)
```

Once the for loop is done, highestEarning will be the highest earning in the list.

Answer (score 0):

`max()` takes an iterable, for example a list.

You probably tried to run max() on a single int, which doesn't work, because how should it? Finding the maximum value of one value is not really a thing.

You can create a list of `ern`and then use max() on this list.

Answer (score 0):

You might use `yield` keyword for your task following way:

```
import empDataLT as x 

def earn():
    empEarn = list() # convert module to a list
    for er in x.a:
        empErn = er.strip().split(",")
        empEarn.append(empErn)
    b = sorted(empEarn, key=lambda x: x[4])
    for e in b:
        ern = (int(e[4]) * int(e[5])) 
        print(ern)
        yield ern
highest = max(earn())
```

For discussion of yield and how to use I suggest [realpython tutorial](https://realpython.com/introduction-to-python-generators/)